# How to add a Defalut-welcome-intent on Dialogflow which is deleted by mistake?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm learning actions on google and I accidentally deleted Default-Welcome-Intent in Dialogflow. So how to add it back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relax! There is nothing magic about the "Default Welcome Intent". In fact, you can call it anything you want. The important bit is that it have the "WELCOME" Event set. You can then add any responses you want, etc.

You can re-create it by creating a new Intent, setting the name, and setting the event. It should look something like this

[image]

Comment: when i open my chatbot, nothing get any welcome message from bot, how to make automaticall message when user just open the chatbot ?

Answer (score 2):

Like Prisoner says, you can create the default welcome or fallback intent again manually.
But I understand that you don't want to rewrite all the basic training phrases or responses or that you're afraid of forgetting something essentially.

Therefore, here is another, more effective way to get your default intents back.

1. Create another project or choose another existing project if you have one.
2. Make sure the default language is the same as your original project.
3. Go to the settings of your new agent and choose the tab 'export and import'.
4. Select 'Export as zip'.
5. Go back to your original project.
6. Go to the settings of your agent and choose the tab 'export and import'.
7. Select 'Import from zip'.
8. Import the zip-file from the other project.
9. [optional] If you exported an already existing project, delete other intents.